# Why does subplot position change?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, subplot

Note: This issue occurs in 2016b in my case.

I try to make a figure with 3x4 subplots together, with tick
labels only on the leftmost and bottom subplots. However, when I run the code below, the first plot seems to change size:

```
figure
hold on
n = 12;
ax = gobjects(n,1);
for k = 1:n
pos = [0.1+0.2*(mod(k-1,4)), 0.65-0.3*floor(k/4-0.01), 0.2, 0.3]
ax(k) = subplot(3,4,k,'Position',pos);
end
set(ax(1:8),'XTick',[])
set(ax([2:4 6:8 10:12]),'YTick',[])
```

Note that I am printing `pos`. The output for the first subplot is

```
pos =

    0.1000    0.6500    0.2000    0.3000
```

but when I then double check the position of the first subplot...

```
ax(1).Position

ans =

    0.1300    0.7093   0.1566    0.2157
```

and the plot looks like this:
[image]

Furthermore, I have tried to manipulate the position of the first subplot afterwards, but it just makes it worse, see below:

```
ax(1).Position = [0.1000, 0.6500, 0.2000, 0.3000];
```

[image]

All help appreciated!

Comment: Can not reproduce in MATLAB 2014b. When I run your code, I get a nice mesh of subplots, all of them tidy.

Comment: Try resizing the figure window

Comment: Also not reproducible in 2016a . This is what I get:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFSnb.jpg

Comment: I see. Thank you for your input! I should have mentioned, the issue occurs in 2016b in my case.

Comment: Also note reproducible in 2015b, I get the same as @Sardar_Usama

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem in R2016b. Interestingly, it works when you do this:

```
figure
hold on
n = 12;
ax = gobjects(n,1);
for k = 1:n
    pos = [0.1+0.2*(mod(k-1,4)), 0.65-0.3*floor(k/4-0.01), 0.2, 0.3]
    ax(k) = subplot(3,4,k);
    set(ax(k),'Position',pos);
end
set(ax(1:8),'XTick',[])
set(ax([2:4 6:8 10:12]),'YTick',[])
```

The only change is that I first create the subplot and then set its position.

I'm not entirely sure of the reason. However, comparing all the fields of the axes in both versions I noticed that in your original version, the first axis has a `PlotBoxAspectRatio` of `[0.9670    1.0000    0.9670]` whereas all other ones have a `PlotBoxAspectRatio` of `[0.8889    1.0000    0.8889]`. In my "fixed" version, all axes have the `PlotBoxAspectRatio` of `[0.8889    1.0000    0.8889]`. Not sure what exactly is happening there.